# dotnet ef database update Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to execute the following line from Package Manager Console for a code first, entity framework project that I've just cloned from our TFS server.  I'm using VS2017.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the package via nuget etc, but I'm at a loss as to what causes this issue and how to resolve it.

Any help, much appreciated.

dotnet ef database update -c DbContext

The resulting output within the Console is as follows:

> Build succeeded.
>       0 Warning(s)
>       0 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:03.12
>
> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions, Version=1.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>
> The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions,
>   Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.StartupInvoker.ConfigureHostServices(IServiceCollection
>   services)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.StartupInvoker.ConfigureServices()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations..ctor(IOperationReporter
>   reporter, Assembly assembly, Assembly startupAssembly, String
>   environment, String contentRootPath)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations..ctor(IOperationReporter
>   reporter, Assembly assembly, Assembly startupAssembly, String
>   environment, String projectDir, String contentRootPath, String
>   rootNamespace)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<.ctor>b__4()
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String
>   targetMigration, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
>   action)
>
> === Pre-bind state information ===
>
> LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions,
>   Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 
>   (Fully-specified)
>
> LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/Users/johnsmith/Source/Repos/myapp/src/myapp-model/bin/Debug/net452/win7-x64
>
> LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
>
> Calling assembly : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions,
>
> ## Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60.
>
> LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
>
> LOG: No application configuration file found.
>
> LOG: Using host configuration file:
>
> LOG: Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>
> LOG: Post-policy reference:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions, Version=1.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
>
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/johnsmith/Source/Repos/myapp/src/myapp-model/bin/Debug/net452/win7-x64/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.DLL.
>
> WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Build
>   Number
>
> ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing
>   terminated.
>
> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions, Version=1.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have this package installed in different projects? Navigate to the **Manage NuGet Packages for Solution** and search for that package in the consolidate tab.
[image]

There you will see the package installed in different projects with different versions. Install the appropriate version and it should work.

[image: Search Nuget Package in installed packages]

Comment: Thanks for the tip Ash.  Nothing appears under consolidate.

Comment: Another possibility is that some of the assemblies you referenced in your project are making use of the older version of this package? Check your packages folder to see the correct DLL there.